# Produce Excel document from SQL data table in vb.net

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, excel, excel-interop

In my project I have a summary data table which i want to export in Excel document, for this purpose i have deployed the following code:

```
Public Shared Function Main() As Integer
        Dim exc As New Application

    exc.Visible = True
        Dim workbooks As Excel.Workbooks = exc.Workbooks
        Dim workbook As Excel._Workbook = workbooks.Add(XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
        Dim sheets As Sheets = workbook.Worksheets
        Dim worksheet As _Worksheet = CType(sheets.Item(1), _Worksheet)
        exc.DataEntryMode = True
        Dim range1 As Range = worksheet.Range("C1", Missing.Value)
        Const nCells As Integer = 5
        Dim args1(1) As [Object]
        args1(0) = nCells
        range1.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, range1, args1)
        Return 100
    End Function
```

When I tried to execute the line:

```
range1.GetType().InvokeMember("Value", BindingFlags.SetProperty, Nothing, range1, args1)
```

I get the error of :
`Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation`
at this point I can't figured out what is the problem. Is there anybody to assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about trying to use invoke member.

To populate a range of values into an Excel documant you can use something like this

```
dim row as integer = 1
dim column as integer = 1


Worksheet.Cells(row,column) = "My value here"
'or this
Worksheet.Cells("A1").Value = "my Value Here"
' or this
Worksheet.Range("A1") = "My value here"
```

Try looking at it from the point of view of doing this inside Excel and then following the same pattern.

**EDIT**
For Text alignement options like word wrap etc.

```
dim rng as Range = Worksheet.Range("A1")
With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
        .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
end With
```

Comment: @Nathan Fisher. Thank you very much everything goes fine. But please tell me this: Why we not invoke member?

Comment: There is no need to invoke member because Range is a known object at compile time.  It would be different if you loaded the Excel Assembly at runtime.

Comment: @Nathan. Thank you very much, tell me please is there any possibility to arrange some row alignments. Like the word wrap from inside of vb.net? Before we populate the document itself

Comment: @Lefteris I assume you are talking about the Cell Text Alignements.  yes there is. check the edit on the answer

Comment: @Nathan. Yes that was it. I want to do more than a thank you, giving some credits but i can't do it from here. Any way thank you very much again.